# where is the play button gone?

Tags: animation

[image]

I must have pressed a keyboard shortcut by mistake, but it's gone for a few days and I can't find any menu to put it back.
What should I do?
Thanks

Comment: it is on the timeline. look at "animation" workspace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The play animation button is not part of the [Dope Sheet](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/editors/dope_sheet/introduction.html), it is in the [Timeline](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/editors/timeline.html). You've likely merged the Timeline area with the Dope Sheet by accident.

In order to add the timeline back:

1. Position your mouse courser between the *Dope Sheet* and the *Properties*. Right-click and select *Horizontal Split*.
   [image: Horizontal split]
   [image: New area]
2. Change the editor type to *Timeline*.
   [image: Change editor type]
   [image: Scale the area]

Comment: Oh thank you! I was getting crazy